# How to modify e-mail body in chatter in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I'm trying to modify email message that gets stored in chatter on an incoming e-mail. Anyone happen to know how to do this? I've spent many hours in email stuff already, and I've been able to do much of what I want but this.

I thought it'd be in message_process , but after trying:

```
msg_txt.set_param('body', 'some body')
```

and

```
custom_values={'body': 'this didn't work either'}
```

Neither of this seems to work. Odoo 11. Thank you!

Comment: Go to settings and change the email template for the model of your choice

Comment: I appreciate your help, but as stated in the message, I'm looking to modify *incoming e-mail*. I believe templates are for outgoing messages.

Comment: Ah! OK, I made a diagonal reading :P. So you want to change the style of the shown messages? Just add classes to the divs you want to change and write the css for them. If you add some screenshot maybe I will understand better